# UIScrollView horizontal

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I cannot get my uiscrollview to scroll horizontally and it is driving me insane. I am able to get it vertically but not horizontally. I have it linked in IB as "scroll" and the rest is done in my viewDidLoad. I am simply trying to scroll through a 8 mini images horizontally. Each image is 160 X 97.

Can someone please tell me why this is not working? Code is below. 
Thank you so much

```
[self->scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self->scroll setDelegate:self];

// [self->scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
// [self->scroll setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault];   scroll.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
scroll.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[self->scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1300.0,50.0)];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];  
scroll.backgroundColor= [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set the scroll frame
like this

```
self.scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,50);
```

Comment: It still only scrolling vertically. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
    scrollview.bounces = YES;
    scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1300, 50);